# strftime model object and display in html template

Tags: python-3.x, django, strftime

Good day, I want to strftime the created model instance and display it in the HTML template(as a transaction_id). But I don't seem to get it right. Thanks for your help.

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    braintree_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(Coupon, related_name='orders', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[
        MinValueValidator(0),
        MaxValueValidator(100)
    ])
```

**views.py**

```
def order_list(request):#datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    transaction_id = Order.objects.get(created)
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    current_user = request.user
    success = Order.objects.filter(user=current_user.id).filter(paid=True)
    fail = Order.objects.filter(user=current_user.id).filter(paid=False)
    return render(request, 'orders/order/order_list.html', {
        'success': success,
        'fail': fail,
        'current_user': current_user,
        'orders':orders,
        'transaction_id':transaction_id,
    })
```

**html**

```
<p class="card-text">
<mark style="color: whitesmoke; background-color: brown;border-radius: 3px;font-weight: bold;">{{transaction_id}}</mark>
</p>
```

Comment: can share the error you are getting?

Comment: `NameError
NameError: name 'created' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

you getting error of "transaction_id = Order.objects.get(created)" line

what is "created" in get() method

Comment: created is in the order model

Comment: I am still confused,

as of my thot, u want created field from the model as transaction_id right ??

transaction_id = Order.objects.get(id=1)

Comment: created is a datetime field in the order model
but I want to display the datetime field as strftime
do you have an idea hopefully?

Comment: u want to display all orders transaction_id??

Comment: views.py
transaction_id = Order.objects.get(id=1) 

html
{{ transaction_id.created }}

Try This...

Comment: yes, i want to display the datetime field 'created' as my transaction id

Comment: try the code

and u have data in Order model right ??

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what I did to fix this
I added the strftime func in my models.py

**models.py**

```
    def htmldisplaytime(self):
        time = self.created.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        return time
```